# A way to RegEx match a Number without a prefix tag?

Tags: vb.net, regex

```html
     1 <span class='Txt9Gray'>Decisions ( </span>
```

I'm trying to grab the `1` from this string. Before the `1` is another `span`, but I can't use that as a marker because it can change from page to page. Is there any regex expression that can simply grab the `1`?

The word `Decisions` will always exist. That's my main way to find this line. Here's what I have been trying to no avail:

```
  strRegex.Append("(?<strDecisionWins>[^<]+)[\s]*?
  <span class='[\s\w\W]*'>\bDecisions\b \([\s\w\W]*?</span>")
```

This keeps grabbing the `spans` before the actual `1`.  The full line containing the above is:

```html
<span class='Txt9Gray'>(T)KOs ( </span> 66.67 <span class='Txt9Gray'>%) </span> <br /> 1 <span class='Txt9Gray'>Decisions ( </span> 33.33 <span class='Txt9Gray'>%) </span> <br />
```

The problem is that the match is matching the very beginning, instead of the one piece.

Comment: What's the whole line look like?

Comment: <span class='Txt9Gray'>(T)KOs ( </span> 66.67 <span class='Txt9Gray'>%) </span> <br />  1 <span class='Txt9Gray'>Decisions ( </span> 33.33 <span class='Txt9Gray'>%) </span> <br /> -- Problem is that the match is matching the very beginning of what I just posted, instead of the one piece.

Comment: I edited your comment into the question so everyone can see it without having to read comments.

Comment: Will the span class always be Txt90Gray?  If so, then you want to grab the digits before " <span class='Txt9Gray'>Decisions".

Comment: that can change. I want the number before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
\d+(?=\s*\<[^\>]+\>[^\<]*\bDecisions\b)
\d+(?=\s*<[^>]+>[^<]*\bDecisions\b)
```

That would only select 1 (and nothing else)

The second form is for regex processor which does not need to escape `<` and `>`.

The lookahead expression `(?=...)` guarantees to select a number `\d+` followed by an element () containing a text (meaning no opening '`<`': `[^<]*`),  which includes the word Decisions.

The lookahead technique can be combined with other regex like:

```
\s\d(?=\s*\<[^\>]+class\s*=\s*'Txt9Gray'[^\>]*\>)
\s\d(?=\s*\<[^>]+class\s*=\s*'Txt9Gray'[^>]*>)
```

would grab a single digit (provided it follows a space), followed by an element containing the attribute '`class='Txt9Gra`y''

Comment: +1 but it seems that escaping the < & > is not necessary (it's not even supported).